# Regex for Persian number

Tags: javascript, regex, farsi

I want to create JavaScript Regex for checking value of textbox in range `(U+06F0 to U+06F9) or (0-9)`
How can I build this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Put the range inside a character class like below.

```
^[\u06F0-\u06F90-9]+$
```

`+` repeats the previous token one or more times.

Comment: why are you using "u0F90-9" ?

Comment: @Hamid Count correctly. He is using `\u06F0-\u06F9` and `0-9`, exactly like you wanted.

Comment: @Hamid consider `\u06F0-\u06F9` and `0-9` as separate parts. Regex engine also parses like this..

Answer (score 3):

You can test the regex pattern on [regexr.com](https://regexr.com) and then use it in your code. I use to match the Persian mobile number with Unicode in blew:
`<\u06F0 to \u06F9>` equal to `<۰-۹>` that matches Persian number like this: `۰۹۱۹۹۱۹۱۱۲۲`.

```
    $("#registerForm").validate({
        rules:{
            mobile:{
                required:true,
                pattern : ^[\u06F0][\u06F0-\u06F9]{3}[\u06F0-\u06F9]{3}[\u06F0-\u06F9]{4},

            },
        },
        messages:{
            mobile:{
                required:"شماره تلفن همراه خود را وارد کنید",
                number:"فقط عدد وارد کنید",
                pattern:"تلفن همراه را به درستی وارد کنید"
            },
        },
        errorClass: "help-inline",
        errorElement: "span",

    });
```

Comment: better to use`^[\u06F0][\u06F9][\u06F0-\u06F9]{2}[\u06F0-\u06F9]{3}[\u06F0-\u06F9]{4}` in pattern. Cause we have only `۹` in second position.

Comment: The pattern should also cover `0-9`.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest this pattern based on my searches:

```
pattern = "^([\u06F0]|[0])([\u06F9]|[9])(([\u06F0-\u06F9]|[0-9]){2})(([\u06F0-\u06F9]|[0-9]){3})(([\u06F0-\u06F9]|[0-9]){4})"
```

It's a little complicated, but works if you want to input both Persian and English numbers in `Persian phone number` format. I've just used `|` as `or`, parentheses for grouping. As @ahmad_mhm mentioned, you can test it on [RegExr](https://regexr.com/).

Answer (score 3):

this pattern is persian Mobile Number for both `09123456789` or `۰۹۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹`

```
 mobileRegExp = /(^09[0-9]{9}$)|(^\u06F0\u06F9[\u06F0-\u06F9]{9})$/
```