# How can I create something like /\d+/ in javascript regexp but with numbers in another language

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to create something like `... .replace(/\d+/g, ...` but not for Latin digits, for Persian digits.
Numbers are: `۱ ۲ ۳ ۴ ۵ ۶ ۷ ۸ ۹ ۰`

I tought I can use something like `... .replace(/۱|۲|۳|۴|۵|۶|۷|۸|۹|۰/g, ...`, but of course, it's not the same.

Comment: have you tried `[۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹]+` in your regex?

Comment: 2 words: character classes. Google it.

Comment: Here is a similar thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28123552/regex-for-persian-number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have a shortcut for non-ASCII digits, so your approach is in the right spirit - you'd better use a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) for this, though:

```
/[۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹۰]+/
```

or

```
/[۱-۰]+/
```