# separate thousands while typing, in Farsi(persian)

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

i'm using this snippet to separate thousands inside input field while user is typing. it works correctly with English letters but doesn't respond to Farsi(persian) ones. Is there any way to make it compatible?

```js
$('input.number').keyup(function(event) {

  // skip for arrow keys
  if (event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;

  // format number
  $(this).val(function(index, value) {
    return value
      .replace(/\D/g, "")
      .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control number" type="text" value="0" name="subjectvalue" id="txt_subjectvalue">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex for persian number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28123552/regex-for-persian-number)

Comment: By changing the first replace to: `.replace(/[^\d\u0660-\u0669\u06f0-\u06f9]+/g,'')` and second replace to `.replace(/[\d\u0660-\u0669\u06f0-\u06f9](?=(?:[\d\u0660-\u0669\u06f0-\u06f9]{3})+(?![\d\u0660-\u0669\u06f0-\u06f9]))/g,'$&,')` it will support Persian/Arabic numbers too. Read more about: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58136480/7514010

Answer (score 2):

This code is for Iranians. This code inserts the comma after Persianizing the numbers.

```js
function insertrialcamma( n ) {
        var m = "";
        for ( var i = 0; i < n.length; i++ ) {
            var c = n.substr( n.length - i - 1, 1 );
            if ( i % 3 == 0 & i > 0 ) {
                m = c + ',' + m;
            } else {
                m = c + m;
            }
        }
        return m;
    }
    function toFarsiNumber( n ) {
        var o = "";
        n = n.toString();
        const farsiDigits = [ '۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '۴', '۵', '۶', '۷', '۸', '۹' ];
        const englishDigits = [ '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' ];
        for ( var i = 0; i < n.length; i++ ) {
            for ( var j = 0; j < englishDigits.length; j++ ) {
                if ( n.substr( i, 1 ) == englishDigits[ j ] ) {
                    o = o + farsiDigits[ j ];
                }
            }
        }
        return o;
    }
    var n = insertrialcamma(toFarsiNumber( '1222345' ));
    alert( n )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [Cleave.js](https://nosir.github.io/cleave.js/) to format your input.

**Update:**

There are many libraries and plugins for it. even you can do it with pure js, Here is [an answer that can help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19470819/3534952).

As the Mood mentioned in his answer, you can use the `replace()` method to do it like below:

```
var fnf = document.getElementById("formattedNumberField");
fnf.addEventListener('keyup', function(evt){
    var n = parseInt(this.value.replace(/\D/g,''),10);
    fnf.value = n.toLocaleString();
}, false);
```

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259)

Answer (score 0):

This code will grab any value the `input` element currently has, remove all the `,` and `.` characters and convert the *String* into a *Number* using [toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) which accepts a *language* parameter:

```js
// listens to an "input" event on the <input> element
document.querySelectorAll('input')[0].addEventListener('input', onInput_Arabic);
document.querySelectorAll('input')[1].addEventListener('input', onInput_normal);

function onInput_normal(){
   // convert into a Number & cleanup the input's value 
   var v = +(this.value.replace(/[,|\.|\D]/g,''));
   // replace the input's value with the formatted wanted value
   this.value =  this.value ? v.toLocaleString() : '';
}

function onInput_Arabic(){
   // convert into a Number & cleanup the input's value 
   // var v = +(this.value.replace(/[,|\.|\D]/g,''));
   var v = transformNumbers.toEnglish( this.value );
   // replace the input's value with the formatted wanted value
   this.value =  this.value ? (+v).toLocaleString('ar-EG') : '';
}

// transforms Numerals from one language system to another
var transformNumbers = (function(){
    var numerals = {
        persian : ["۰", "۱", "۲", "۳", "۴", "۵", "۶", "۷", "۸", "۹"],
        arabic  : ["٠", "١", "٢", "٣", "٤", "٥", "٦", "٧", "٨", "٩"]
    };

    function fromEnglish(str, lang){
        var i, len = str.length, result = "";

        for( i = 0; i < len; i++ )
            result += numerals[lang][str[i]]; 

        return result;
    }

    return {
        toEnglish : function(str){
            var num, i, len = str.length, result = "";

            for( i = 0; i < len; i++ ){
                num = numerals["persian"].indexOf(str[i]);
                num = num != -1 ? num : numerals["arabic"].indexOf(str[i]);
                if( num == -1 ) continue // num = str[i];
                result += num; 
            }
              
            return result;
        },

        toPersian : function(str, lang){
            return fromEnglish(str, "persian");
        },

        toArabic : function(str){
            return fromEnglish(str, "arabic");
        }
    }
})();
```

```css
input{ width:90%; display:block; padding:5px; margin:1em 0; }
```

```html
<input placeholder='Type Number in Eastern-Arabic (٢٤٦٦٩٢٤٦٦٩)'>

<input placeholder='Type Number in common language (123456) '>
```

---

Check my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32154217/104380) on how to convert a number String into a "thousands" separated String, and for only allowing numbers in the input, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1862219/104380).

Comment: this doesn't respond to persian numbers